# Calculate an age from a DateTime in Years.Months format?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Does anyone have an algorithm in c# to accurately calculate an age given a DateTime in the format Years.Months?

eg.

- DOB: 6-Sep-1988
- Answer: 23.4
- DOB: 31-Mar-1991
- Answer: 20.10
- DOB: 25-Feb-1991
- Answer: 20.11

thanks

Comment: did you checked TimeSpan struct  ???

Comment: @Ravi: Did you think about whether that can accurately determine the number of months and years between two dates?

Comment: no, thought of suggesting NodaTime, but when "daemon" is alive on SO, then why to worry, you will come up with solid eg :)

Comment: The important point is, the answer could be different depending on the localized calendar you use. Consider the recent loss of a day in Western Samoa for instance. Can we assume the subject was born in this timezone?

Comment: @Jodrell: That's not a *calendar* anomaly, that's a *time zone* anomaly. There's a subtle difference there. (The answer *does* depend on the calendar, of course - for example, in a Hebrew calendar it would be reasonable to have an answer of "10 years, 12 months" - but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I agree its subtle and the Western Samoa example is "just" a change of time zone. Sticking to just the Gregorian Calenadar it would be important to know the exact distribution of "leaps" for instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) fairly easily:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowAge(1988, 9, 6);
        ShowAge(1991, 3, 31);
        ShowAge(1991, 2, 25);
    }

    private static readonly PeriodType YearMonth =
        PeriodType.YearMonthDay.WithDaysRemoved();

    static void ShowAge(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        var birthday = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
        // For consistency for future readers :)
        var today = new LocalDate(2012, 2, 3);

        Period period = Period.Between(birthday, today, YearMonth);
        Console.WriteLine("Birthday: {0}; Age: {1} years, {2} months",
                          birthday, period.Years, period.Months);
    }
}
```

Doing it with *just* .NET's `DateTime` support would be possible, but you'd have to do the arithmetic yourself, basically. And it almost certainly wouldn't be as clear. Not that I'm biased or anything :)

Comment: *You*, a *bias*, about *DateTime*? Noooo... ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: You've got to admit, that is pretty sweet code though :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Fixed, thanks. I sometimes put sf.net instead of googlecode.com as that's where Joda Time is :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! And yes; the code made me think, "I *have* to check this thing out".

Comment: Thanks for this. Noda Time looks interesting but, I was hoping to just rely on the .NET API.

Comment: @greg.pakes: Then you'll have to do more work, I'm afraid. One simplistic approach would be to *guess* then number of years (subtract one year from another) then try close values until you're less than a year before "now", then do the same for months. It's fiddly though.

Answer (score 3):

This method doesn't require any external libraries:

```
private static string AgeInYearsMonths(DateTime? DateOfBirth)
{
    if (DateOfBirth == null) return "";
    if (DateOfBirth >= DateTime.Today)
        throw new ArgumentException("DateOfBirth cannot be in future!");

    DateTime d = DateOfBirth.Value;
    int monthCount = 0;
    while ((d = d.AddMonths(1)) <= DateTime.Today)
    {
        monthCount++;
    }
    return string.Format("{0}.{1}", monthCount / 12, monthCount % 12);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var date=new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1988,10,31)).Ticks);
Console.WriteLine((date.Year-1).ToString()+"."+(date.Month-1).ToString());
```

Comment: This will be completely broken in a number of situations. For example, take a birthday of Feb 1st 2012, with a "today" or March 1st 2012... that's 29 days ago, which would give 0 months using this code.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: It really doesn't. It's broken.

Comment: What @JonSkeet said is what I should have said! I was talking about something different; it's not broken in the way I was suggesting.

Comment: @linkerro: I have - I've given a concrete example of why it's broken. Basically you've neglected the fact that "60 days" represents a different number of months depending on the start point. (Also, by taking `Month` like this, you'll *never* return 0, and you *can* return 12, which I doubt is the intention.)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out while explaining it to a friend. I also figured out the ToString (lately I forget that c# doesn't have automatic casting)

Comment: @linkerro: Um, the string part was fine.

Comment: I'm not sure that in most applications there is a major difference between the different values "60 days" can take.